Hyperbolic parallel lines of constant distance
Is it possible to have two distinct hyperbolic lines at a constant distance from each other?
To clarify: I mean that two lines $p$ and $q$ are at a constant distance from each other if $\exists c\in [0,\infty)$ such that for each point $x\in p$ the shortest distance from $x$ to $p$ is c.
In the upper half plane model, I can imagine drawing two concentric circles with different radii intersecting the boundary to be parallel geodesics in hyperbolic space. In Euclidean space these lines will remain at a constant distance from each other, but in hyperbolic space I think that the distance between these lines will increase as a point on one line approaches the boundary. Two Euclidean distinct half lines in the upper half plane model would not be at a constant distance from each other by the same reasoning.
Maybe the line at a constant distance from a geodesic in hyperbolic space is not a geodesic?
Sorry for the lack of rigor. I am thinking visually but I would not mind having a discussion with some formulas.

added some detail on unit speed geodesics...

years ago https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/950000/exponential-map-in-the-poincar%C3%A9-upper-half-plane/950027#950027

These are called equidistant curves, sometimes hypercycles.
In the upper half plane model, a geodesic is either a vertical ray or a semicircle with diameter on the $x$ axis. Given the two "endpoints"  on the $x$ axis, an equidistant curve is a different circular arc that meets those two points as well.
Perhaps easier to see: take a geodesic as a vertical ray, maybe just the $y$ axis $x=0.$ Two equidistant curves, one on either side, are given by infinite rays. For some positive number $c,$ the rays are $y = cx$   and $y = -cx,$  both with $y>0$   as usual.
Writing as the complex numbers, we have parametrisation $z = t w $   for real $t$  and fixed complex $w;$   the other side is $z = -t \bar{w}.$
For example, take $w = 1 + i.$ First question: why is this "equidistant"  from ray $z = ti?$
Added:  this is worth proving:: the unit speed parametrization of the vertical type of geodesic, on the real axis it   hits some $x_0,$   is
$$ x_0 + i e^t $$
or a time shift taking $t \mapsto t - t_0$
The semicircle type, center some real $x_0$  and ambient radius $R > 0$  is  unit speed
$$ x_0 + R \tanh t  + i R \operatorname{sech} t$$
First prove this (with $x_0 = 0$)  for $i e^t$ being unit speed. Then, the Mobius transformation $f(z) = \frac{z-1}{z+1}$   takes that ray to a standard semicircle with "center" at $0$  other endpoints at $1, -1$  and a point at $i.$ Mobius transformations are isometries, $m(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$  with real $a,b,c,d$   and $ad - bc > 0$

Thanks you! I am unfamiliar with taking distances in the hyperbolic plane using complex numbers so I will translate to Euclidean coordinates. Taking $w=1+i$ we have a line $y=x$. Take a fixed point $(x,x)$ on $y=x$, then the distance between $(x,x)$ and a point $(0,t)$ on $x=0$ can be expressed by $2$arcsinh$(\sqrt(x^2+(x-t)^2))/(2\sqrt(tx))$ (formula from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_half-plane_model#Distance_calculation). I imagine you find the value of $t$ which minimizes the function and calculate the distance between the curves, but this seems complicated.
